Shopify APP Development - Discount Function - i18N - Translation Issue
I am trying to build a Shopify APP (Discount Function) using Remix.
This is the tutorial which I am following Build UI With Remix
I am facing issue with translation where I am getting following error
Error: Missing translation for key: DiscountAppComponents.SummaryCard.title in locale: en
    at translate (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-HF6XFBDG.js?v=0727164a:1604:9)
    at I18n.translate (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-HF6XFBDG.js?v=0727164a:1864:14)
    at SummaryCard (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/@shopify_discount-app-components.js?v=0727164a:16848:11)
    at renderWithHooks (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-FB76QECL.js?v=0727164a:11548:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-FB76QECL.js?v=0727164a:14926:21)
    at beginWork (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-FB76QECL.js?v=0727164a:15914:22)
    at beginWork$1 (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-FB76QECL.js?v=0727164a:19753:22)
    at performUnitOfWork (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-FB76QECL.js?v=0727164a:19198:20)
    at workLoopSync (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-FB76QECL.js?v=0727164a:19137:13)
    at renderRootSync (https://metal-lender-why-ng.trycloudflare.com/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-FB76QECL.js?v=0727164a:19116:15)

I believe this is the file where error is coming from discount-ui\extensions\product-discount\locales\en.default.json. File content below:
{
  "name": "product-discount",
  "description": "product-discount",
  "DiscountAppComponents": {
    "SummaryCard": {
      "title": "Summary"
    }
  }
}

